# PHP - Getting a URL within a function argument

Tags: php, function

I have the below function that works perfect when I put the URL string within the argument manually. I need it to be dynamic though and I am using Wordpress.

```
    function get_tweets($url) {     
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' .  $url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
return intval( $json['count'] );
}
// Below is the one that works manually     
<?php echo get_tweets('http://www.someurl.com');

//ones I have tried that do not (trying to make dynamic)
$url = $get_permalink();

echo get_tweets('$url');
echo get_tweets($url);

$url = '$get_permalink()'; 
$url = $get_permalink(); // produces needs to be in string error
echo get_tweets($url);
```

Comment: what is result of `var_dump($url)` ?

Comment: string(16) "$get_permalink()"

Comment: change `$url = $get_permalink();` to `$url = get_permalink();`

Comment: I TOTALLY figured out what I did wrong, thank you GBD. I was making a function a variable with the get_permalink. This is the working code. $url = get_permalink(); <?php echo get_tweets($url); ?>

Comment: yes thank you. That is the problem when pulling all nighters! lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with what you're doing, per se. The only obvious mistake I can see is that you aren't encoding the URL properly. You need to ensure the query string arguments you put in the URL are properly URL encoded, otherwise the remote host may not interpret the request correctly.

```
function get_tweets($url) {     
    $json_string = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' .  urlencode($url));
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return intval( $json['count'] );
}

echo get_tweets('http://www.someurl.com'); // should work just fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your url String?

```
urlencode($foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is on below line

Change

```
//ones I have tried that do not (trying to make dynamic)
$url = $get_permalink();
```

To

```
//ones I have tried that do not (trying to make dynamic)
$url = get_permalink();
```